# How to convert WordPress plugins to use WP REST API

Tags: wordpress, wp-api

I've been reading about WP API and I love the idea however is it far enough along to use? For instance I want to build a custom react front end but use the WP API. My concern is that I won't have access to certain plugin information. Is it possible to hook in and create a custom end point for plugins that do not support WP API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is indeed possible. You can for example [add values to the response](http://v2.wp-api.org/extending/modifying/), [add support for custom post types](http://v2.wp-api.org/extending/custom-content-types/) or [add fully custom endpoints](http://v2.wp-api.org/extending/adding/).

Please note that v1 will be replaced by v2 of the API. v2 is still a work in progress - has been for a while - and will introduce a lot of breaking changes, so it would be better to use the [latest beta version of the API](https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API).